# What is wrong with this sha 256 function?

Tags: c++, sha, crypto++

I'm starting to use crypto++ lib and maybe I have some misconceptions.

I don't realize why the following code produces a bad sha 256

```
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
# include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
# include <cryptopp/sha.h>
# include <cryptopp/hex.h>

using namespace std;

string sha256_hex(const string & str)
{
  byte digest[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];
  CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(digest, (byte*) &str[0], str.size());

  string ret;
  CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
  encoder.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ret));
  encoder.Put(digest, sizeof(digest));
  encoder.MessageEnd();

  return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto sha256 = sha256_hex(argv[1]);
  cout << "str     = " << argv[1] << endl
       << "sha 256 = " << sha256_hex(sha256) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The following command

```
./test-sha256 hello
```

produces the following output

```
str     = hello
sha 256 = DD9F20FF4F1DD817C567DE6C16915DC0A731A4DF51088F55CEF4CD2F89CF9620
```

However according to this online calculator [enter link description here](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator), the correct sha 256 for `"hello"` would be `2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824`.

So my question is what am I doing wrong?

I have an additional question: how and when the memory used by the `StringSink` object should be freed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @lrleon i am facing this kind of error --> error: undefined reference to 'vtable for CryptoPP::SHA256'
I wants to generate SHA256 with cryptopp, can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aren't you computing the hash of the hash here? You call `sha256_hex` twice, once with `argv[1]` as argument, and once with `sha256` itself as argument.

Answer (score 2):

As for the second part of the question:

In the Crypto++ [Pipelining system](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining), filters and sinks are owned by the object they are attached to. They are automatically deleted by the destructor of that object.

And from "Important Usage Notes" in [ReadMe.txt](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/Readme.txt):

> If a constructor for A takes a pointer to an object B (except primitive types such as int and char), then A owns B and will delete B at A's destruction. If a constructor for A takes a reference to an object B, then the caller retains ownership of B and should not destroy it until A no longer needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, I see the problem is here:

```
CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(digest, (byte*) &str[0], str.size());
```

You better pass `str.c_str()`. Use debugger to see what exactly is being passed - does it translate to `hello` ?

Comment: @lrleon Yep, use the debugger and.or add print statements, that is a part of developing code. SO is not you debugger, it is the last resort help after you have done the basic debugging.

Comment: How is the value returned from `&str[0]` and `str.c_str()` different? Surely, this is not guaranteed by the C++ Standard, but have you ever come across an implementation, where those expressions aren't semantically identical? I have no idea, why this 'answer' got upvoted....

Comment: `&str[0]` is correct because it provides a non-const pointer. `str.c_str()` provides a cont-pointer, and writing to it is undefined behavior.